# Start and end location for a completed trip with uber-api

Tags: uber-api

my girlfriend and I have some cool statistics to provide for an uber user, but without start and end location, is basically impossible.

Given the current API, that's what we tried:

- ***GET /v1.2/history***: provide some information, but related to location, only the city where the ride happened
- ***GET /v1/requests/{request_id}***: give location only for in_progress rides
- ***GET /v1/requests/{request_id}/map:*** here was the closest place we got. After some element inspection we figure it out that there is a json nested in the html that provide this information. But again, when generating maps for each ride, most of them gave us this error: (that based on answer that we found in another question here, its because maps are available only for a couple of days): {'code': 'conflict', 'message': 'Unable to generate map for trip "6a31e621-2c6f-4422-ac74-e9f382b346c5"'}

There is some way to retrieve this information or has someone successfully done this?

I mean, I don't know if they hide this information because privacy concerns. But, during some time we have the information. It's all about timing, If this is because a privacy concern, why they provide this temporarily, then, hide. If anyone know about the way that it works (you can make sure they search  more than us about this), they are already collecting this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not currently provide start and end location for all trips via the history end point. Currently, we only provide start / end location for in progress trips. Your understanding above is correct.

Comment: can we add an enhancement request to provide the start and end location for a completed trip - or - at least, at a minimum the end location?

Comment: Something like a year has passed. Any changes to the API for getting end location?

Comment: I don't think so @lonlywolf. I just looked into it and still they give us just the start city.